# Apollo Cache Redirects With a Returned Payload

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Going off Apollo's cacheRedirect example (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching.html#cacheRedirect)

Now, I make the following schema modification...

```
type Query {
   books: [BookPayload!]!
}
type BookPayload {
   books: [Book!]!
   // other stuff, e.g. bookCount: Int
}
```

In the example, Apollo can check if any returned books are in the cache by:

```
cacheRedirects: {
  Query: {
    books: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) =>
      args.ids.map(id =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: 'Book', id: id }))
  }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to redirect the cache when the type being checked isn't directly returned.  I've tried every permutation of return to no avail.

Any help is really appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're question is unclear. You say "I'm not sure how to redirect the cache when the type being checked isn't directly returned," but you appear to be checking and returning `[BookPayload!]!`

Therefore I see no reason why this wouldn't work:

```
cacheRedirects: {
  Query: {
    books: (_, args, { getCacheKey }) =>
      args.ids.map(id =>
        getCacheKey({ __typename: 'BookPayload', id: id }))
  }
}
```

Comment: Book payload has no id.  It's simply a container.  Also, even if it had an id, that wouldn't work because you need to match the books to the cache, not BookPayload

Comment: @D.Walsh Hm. So there is only 1 `BookPayload` then? I think its saved in the cache with an id of `"$ROOT_QUERY.books"` then (or maybe `"ROOT_QUERY.books"`). I'm not sure if that would work for the cache key function though. You could also try passing `undefined` as the ID.

Comment: @D.Walsh if you use the [Apollo Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm) to examine the store, you should be able to see the ID it has.